# Parsing Mutation Data in R

Tags: r

I'm interested in parsing out some mutation data but struggling with different approaches to accommodate each possibility. I have the following example string of mutation data:

```
muts=c("S267P", "W290*","K650Q")
```

and I would like to create a simple data from where the reference (first letter), numerical position and alternate form are parsed out. For example, if we look at the first entry, the Ref would be 'S', the position would be 267 and the Alt would be P. Any ideas o the best way to create a generic function to match and split out these into respective groups, etc. I've tried grep and stringr but had trouble getting all three pieces separated, etc.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) strcapture** Assuming that the first field is non-numeric (`\\D+`), the second is numeric (`\\d+`) and the third is non-numeric (`\\D+`) we can use `stracapture` from base R. If we knew that the fields were fixed width we could use the pattern `(.)(...)(.)` instead.

```
# pat <- "(.)(...)(.)"  # alternative if fields fixed width
pat <- "(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)"
strcapture(pat, muts, list(Ref = character(0), Pos = integer(0), Alt = character(0)))
```

giving this data.frame:

```
  Ref Pos Alt
1   S 267   P
2   W 290   *
3   K 650   Q
```

**1a) read.pattern** `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package is somewhat similar to the `strcapture` solution using the same pattern but not requiring that the fields be explicitly typed.  It gives the same output.  `pat` is defined in (1).

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = muts, pattern = pat, as.is = TRUE, 
  col.names = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"))
```

**2) read.table** Using the same assumptions as (1) we can insert a space to either side of the numeric part and then read it in using `read.table`.  This is also a base solution giving the same output as above.

```
read.table(text = sub("(\\d+)", " \\1 ", muts), as.is = TRUE,
  col.names = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"))
```

**3) read.fwf** Assuming the fields are fixed width we can use `read.fwf` from base R.  The output is the same as above. No regular expressions are used.

```
read.fwf(textConnection(muts), c(1, 3, 1), as.is = TRUE,
  col.names = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"))
```

giving:

```
  Ref Pos Alt
1   S 267   P
2   W 290   *
3   K 650   Q
```

**4) substr** Yet another base solution using the same assumptions as (3) and giving the same output as above is:

```
data.frame(Ref = substr(muts, 1, 1),
  Pos = as.integer(substr(muts, 2, 4)),
  Alt = substr(muts, 5, 5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**5) separate**  Assuming the fields are in fixed positions we can use the tidyr package's `separate`.  Again, no regular expressions are used.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

tibble(muts) %>%
  separate(muts, into = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"), sep = c(1, 4, 5))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Ref   Pos   Alt  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 S     267   P    
2 W     290   *    
3 K     650   Q
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Not clear about the expected output, we can create a delimiter and then split with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text = sub("(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)$", "\\1,\\2,\\3", muts),
       header = FALSE, col.names = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"))
#    Ref Pos Alt
#1   S 267   P
#2   W 290   *
#3   K 650   Q
```

**2)** Or another option with `strsplit`

```
type.convert(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
    strsplit(muts,  "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", perl = TRUE))))
```

---

**3)** Or another option is regex lookarounds (which would also cover different number of characters)

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(muts) %>%
   separate(muts, into = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"), "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Ref   Pos   Alt  
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 S     267   P    
#2 W     290   *    
#3 K     650   Q
```

**4)** Or we can use `extract`

```
tibble(muts) %>%
   extract(muts, into = c("Ref", "Pos", "Alt"), "(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)")
```